# Getting inconsistent data while using async/await in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
var fetchLeadsFor24hours = async function (clientConfig, user, cardsResponse, promises, query) {
    if (clientConfig.code !== CLIENT_CODE) {
        return; 
    }

    var state = ['Open', 'Follow Up', 'Appointment Scheduled'];
    const LEADS = models.getModel(models.LEAD, clientConfig.code);
    const query1 = {
        deleted: false,
        first_update_type: { '$in': ['two_wheeler_loan_new', 'auto_loans_bau_vertical__new'] }
    };

    var filterQuery = {};

    if (query.self === true) {
        user = query.vymo_user_code;
        filterQuery = _.extend(query1, {
            "user.code": user
        });
    } else {
        filterQuery = _.extend(query1, {
            "authorised_group_regions": query.region
        });
    }

    var handleCountAndAddCards = function (eachState, leads) {
        var diffInHoursPromises = leads.map(function (lead) {
            var lastUpdateDate = new Date(_.get(lead, 'last_update_date', ''));
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var diffInMilliseconds = currentTime.getTime() - lastUpdateDate.getTime();
            var diffInHours = diffInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            return diffInHours;
        });

        Promise.all(diffInHoursPromises).then(function (diffInHoursArray) {
            var card1 = cardsResponse.cards.find(card => card.name === 'Back Log Less Than 24 Hours');
            var card2 = cardsResponse.cards.find(card => card.name === 'Back Log Greater Than 24 Hours');

            if (card1 && card2) {
                var categories1 = card1.pages[0].categories;
                var categories2 = card2.pages[0].categories;

                var categories1Copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories1));
                var categories2Copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories2));
                switch (eachState) {
                    case 'Open':
                        categories1Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Open').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time < 24).length;
                        categories2Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Open').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time >= 24).length;
                        break;
                    case 'Follow Up':
                        categories1Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Follow Up').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time < 24).length;
                        categories2Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Follow Up').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time >= 24).length;
                        break;
                    case 'Appointment Scheduled':
                        categories1Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Appointment Scheduled').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time < 24).length;
                        categories2Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Appointment Scheduled').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time >= 24).length;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                categories1Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Total').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time < 24).length;
                categories2Copy.find(cat => cat.name === 'Total').value += diffInHoursArray.filter(time => time >= 24).length;

                card1.pages[0].categories = categories1Copy;
                card2.pages[0].categories = categories2Copy;
            } else {
                var newCards = {
                    type: 'leads',
                    name: 'Back Log Less Than 24 Hours',
                    module: 'two_wheeler_loan_new',
                    pages: [
                        {
                            code: "vo_last_state.7whkih9jrr",
                            name: "All Lead Summary",
                            categories: [
                                {
                                    code: "commercial_vehical_new.1lpq8esmdo",
                                    name: "Open",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Open') ? leads.length : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "met_scheduled_followup_commercial_vehical.wr0cibixy",
                                    name: "Follow Up",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Follow Up') ? leads.length : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "first_meeting_scheduled_commercial_vehical.18eek78wm",
                                    name: "Appointment Scheduled",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Appointment Scheduled') ? leads.length : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "9wnhs",
                                    name: "Total",
                                    value: leads.length,
                                    color: ""
                                }
                            ],
                            computed: false
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var totalCards = {
                    type: 'leads',
                    name: 'Back Log Greater Than 24 Hours',
                    module: 'two_wheeler_loan_new',
                    pages: [
                        {
                            code: "vo_last_state.7whkih9jrr",
                            name: "All Lead Summary",
                            categories: [
                                {
                                    code: "commercial_vehical_new.1lpq8esmdo",
                                    name: "Open",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Open') ? 0 : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "met_scheduled_followup_commercial_vehical.wr0cibixy",
                                    name: "Follow Up",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Follow Up') ? 0 : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "first_meeting_scheduled_commercial_vehical.18eek78wm",
                                    name: "Appointment Scheduled",
                                    value: (eachState === 'Appointment Scheduled') ? 0 : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    code: "9wnhs",
                                    name: "Total",
                                    value: 0,
                                    color: ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };

                if (!card1) {
                    cardsResponse.cards.push(newCards);
                }

                if (!card2) {
                    cardsResponse.cards.push(totalCards);
                }
            }

            console.log(`Count: ${leads.length}, DiffInHours: ${diffInHoursArray}, State: ${eachState}`);
        });
    };

    var batchSize = 100;
    var skip = 0;
    var totalCount = 0;

    while (true) {
        var stateQuery = Object.assign({}, filterQuery);

        state.forEach(function (eachState) {
            switch (eachState) {
                case 'Open':
                    _.extend(stateQuery, {
                        last_update_type: { '$in': ['two_wheeler_loan_new', 'auto_loans_bau_vertical__new'] }
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Follow Up':
                    _.extend(stateQuery, {
                        last_update_type: { '$in': ['first_meeting_rescheduled_two_wheeler_loan', 'met_scheduled_followup_auto_loans_bau_vertical_'] }
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Appointment Scheduled':
                    _.extend(stateQuery, {
                        last_update_type: { '$in': ['first_meeting_scheduled_auto_loans_bau_vertical_', 'first_meeting_scheduled_two_wheeler_loan'] }
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            var findLeadsPromise = LEADS.find(stateQuery).select('last_update_type last_update_date').skip(skip).limit(batchSize).lean().exec();

            promises.push(findLeadsPromise.then(function (leads) {
                handleCountAndAddCards(eachState, leads);
                totalCount += leads.length;
            }));
        });

        var leadsCount = await LEADS.count(stateQuery);
        if (totalCount >= leadsCount) {
            break;
        }
        skip += batchSize;
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Here I am trying to fetch the leads from database
And showing the count on UI
query I am creating based on some states
After that Based on Last_update_type property of lead
We are categorizing the leads to 2 different cards
if Last_update_type is less than 24hours from now I need to push the lead count to 1st card or else in 2nd card

Here I am facing the issue where query is fetching leads count correctly
but after every refresh counts are getting swapped between 2 cards

Screenshots attached
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using await with Promise.all(diffInHoursPromises)?